# ASP.NET Core OpenIdConnect and admin consent on the same callback path

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect

I have implemented an OpenIdConnect with Azure. The code is approximately like this:

```
            var options = new OpenIdConnectOptions
            {
                SignInScheme = PersistentSchemeName,
                CallbackPath = "/oauth2office2",
                ClientId = pubConf.ApplicationId,
                Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{configuration.TenantId}"
            };
```

It works perfectly.
But I also need admin consent and I don't want my users to add two CallbackPaths into my app.
So I crafted admin consent url manually.
And added a redirect so it won't conflict with a OpenId middleware:

```
        app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().Add(context =>
        {
            var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
            if (request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/oauth2office2") && request.Method == HttpMethods.Get)
            {
                request.Path = "/oauth2office";
            }
        }));
```

Now i have a controller at `/oauth2office` that does some extra stuff for me (actually gets tenant id).

Question - is there a way I can achieve it with OpenIdConnect middleware? While still being on the same callback path.
Because adding two paths is an extra i want to avoid.
I'm not even sure I can make OpenIdConnect work with admin consent actually.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add two AddOpenIDConnect(...) instances with different schema names and different callback endpoints?

You can only have one endpoint per authentication handler.

Also, do be aware that the callback request to the openidconnect handler is done using HTTP **POST**, like

POST /signin-oidc HTTP/1.1

In your code you are looking for a GET

```
if (request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/oauth2office2") && request.Method == HttpMethods.Get)
```

Comment: Does it support admin consent flow actually? I haven't tried yet. But having two endpoints makes configuration less error prone. User will need to enter two. I think one endpoint is more than enough for user to configure.
I think i will do the following - probably have two registrations but rewrite will go to one or another depending on the required flow.

Comment: see my updated answer, that Is a more proper approach of implementing this.

Comment: I don't use Identity Server. Admin consent and User login are separate features. Consent is needed for application to work in the backend using certificate to access Graph (App permissions involved, no access token requested). User login doesn't ask for anything except id token, just to convert id token into my own cookie (No delegate permissions involved, no access token requested).
They're separate. Just wonder if i can make them with one callback path.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a single OpenIdConnect handler by overriding the events RedirectToIdentityProvider and MessageReceived.

```
    public override async Task RedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Properties.Items.TryGetValue("AzureTenantId", out var azureTenantId))
            azureTenantId = "organizations";

        if (context.Properties.Items.TryGetValue("AdminConsent", out var adminConsent) && adminConsent == "true")
        {
            if (context.Properties.Items.TryGetValue("AdminConsentScope", out var scope))
                context.ProtocolMessage.Scope = scope;
            context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress =
                $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{azureTenantId}/v2.0/adminconsent";
        }

        await base.RedirectToIdentityProvider(context);
    }

    public override async Task MessageReceived(MessageReceivedContext context)
    {
        // Handle admin consent endpoint response.
        if (context.Properties.Items.TryGetValue("AdminConsent", out var adminConsent) && adminConsent == "true")
        {
            if (!context.ProtocolMessage.Parameters.ContainsKey("admin_consent"))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Expected admin_consent parameter");

            var redirectUri = context.Properties.RedirectUri;
            var parameters = context.ProtocolMessage.Parameters.ToQueryString();
            redirectUri += redirectUri.IndexOf('?') == -1
                ? "?" + parameters
                : "&" + parameters;
            context.Response.Redirect(redirectUri);
            context.HandleResponse();
            return;
        }

        await base.MessageReceived(context);
    }
```

Then when you need to do admin consent, craft a challenge with the correct properties:

```
    public IActionResult Register()
    {
        var redirectUrl = Url.Action("RegisterResponse");
        var properties = new OpenIdConnectChallengeProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = redirectUrl,
            Items =
            {
                { "AdminConsent", "true" },
                { "AdminConsentScope", "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }
            }
        };

        return Challenge(properties, "AzureAd");
    }

    public IActionResult RegisterResponse(
        bool admin_consent,
        string tenant,
        string scope)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Admin Consent for tenant {tenant}: {admin_consent} {scope}", tenant, admin_consent,
            scope);
        return Ok();
    }
```